# Нет перевода строк по поводу ивента на 1 апреля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, 1-апреля

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А, теперь врубился, что это за машина времени! :)))

Comment: Для полноты нужно перевести Guestbook и картинки. Да и вообще через traducir можно весь сайт перестроить под http://coolkolyan.com/

Comment: А чего за война правок?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ где? -_+

Comment: Ну, прямо тут, судя по ревизиям.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ откатил к оригиналу, т.к. не люблю, когда без причины правят мои посты.

Comment: Почему без причины? В описании правки же как раз указана причина.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я использовал англицизм, а не миксовал разные языки.

Comment: Что-то я не уверен в том, что "ивент" является англицизмом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11714

Предложил:

> Назад в будущее!

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11709

Предложил:

> Как и 90-е, хорошие вещи приходят к концу. Если вы хотите
>   переключиться на обычный дизайн, нажмите тут.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11691

> Путешествие во времени!

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11697

> Отметьтесь в гостевой книге!

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11696

> Имя:

Comment: "Как и 90-е, хорошие вещи приходят к концу"
Хмм, у среднего жителя России эта строка вызовет недоумение

Comment: @AntonSorokin ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AntonSorokin "Как и 90-е, лихие вещи приходят к концу" :)

Comment: Кому как, я бы не хотел повтора 90-х

Comment: @AntonSorokin "Как и наше детство в девяностых, всё хорошее рано или поздно должно закончиться. Нажмите сюда, чтобы вернуть привычный дизайн сайта."

Comment: @Arhad предложите в традусёре)

Comment: @Suvitruf Сделано. Заодно обнаружил там баг: предложенный мной перевод не показывается даже после Ctrl+F5. Но судя по ошибке при повторной отправке (https://i.stack.imgur.com/87rNq.png), мой вариант всё-таки был добавлен в список.

Comment: @Arhad да, traducir глючит, без очистки кеша регулярно показывает устаревшую информацию, по крайней мере в браузерах на движке хрома. У меня ваш вариант отображается

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил покрасивее:

> Назад в будущее! 
>   Как и 90-е, приятные вещи всегда имеют конец. Если
>   вы хотите вернуться на прежний сайт, кликните здесь.

Comment: _"Как и в 90-е"_ - не "в 90е", а сами "девяностые". Но возможно в локализации стоит подобрать другое событие?